# How to make the value of select element to the center position in the Bootstrap framework

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center the value of a `select` element. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.

Normally, with other elements, we can add a `text-center` class to them. However, it doesn't work when applying that class to the select element. If I add the class to each of the options contained within the select element, it still doesn't work.

Here is a code snippet and an image:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <select class="form-control text-center" ng-model="immunization['D2002.35']">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Yes" class="text-center">Yes</option>
    <option value="No" class="text-center">No</option>
  `enter code here`</select>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It is best not to use the css which is wrote by ourselves.I just want to know whether there is a solution which is suitable to this situation in the bootstrap framework.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no specific Bootstrap classes to do that as far as I know.

But the solution seems pretty simple:

```
option {
  text-align: left;
}
select {
  text-align-last: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**[JSFiddle for demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/28a39shs/)**.